# AngularJS - reroute # to #!

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hashbang

I'm using the $routeProvider and have just set it up to use hashbang.

Now all external links are incorrect since they reffer to "mysite/#/page"

Is it possible to make the $routeProvider re-route any "mysite/#/page" link to "mysite/#!/page" ?

I've changed all internal links so they are ok, but external links on other sites will stop working otherwise.

Comment: $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

Answer (score 0):

You can patch up the URL right before Angular starts like this:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
if (url.indexOf('#') > - 1) {
    window.location = url.replace('#', '#!');
}
```